# Markdown analog for SVG

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, markdown

I am using [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) format to represent content (articles, problem statements) on pages of my site. Now I want to add some pictures or drawings to text sometimes.

I think of using SVG element embedded into HTML instead of storing raster images. And markdown processes this all right (if svg is enclosed in div element).

However, SVG format itself is not as simple as markdown and I now wonder, whether there exists some markdown-like processor which can take the commands in some simple format like:

```
svg 200, 150
set-color black
set-fill none
rect 0, 0, 200, 150
set-color #C00
set-fill #F00
circle 100, 75, 50
```

and convert it to svg element. Does anybody encountered something of the kind?

I think that javascript and canvas will do also if there is such markdown-like processor for them...

Comment: Well, I'm sure you have your reasons, so maybe what I'm writing is not that helpful, but the whole idea of markdown is to be easy to write and easy to read – that the intended formatting of the text is obvious even if you haven't studied the syntax. And I don't see how you could achieve something analogous to that for vector graphics; however simple the syntax, it will never be easy to read, it just has to be converted into something to look at. Therefore I'd recommend to prepare illustrations in separate files and then include them via the `![]()` syntax.

Answer (score 7):

I don’t know of any Markdown-to-SVG parsers, but it’s not very hard to build one.

Here’s a Fiddle Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/aPg8a/

[image]

**Start with an Svg “class” that knows how to create SVG elements in javascript**

(Code for this Svg class is further below)

This Svg class knows how to do these SVG tasks:

- Create a parent html svg element ( new Svg )
- Set the size of the svg element ( .setSvgWidthHeight )
- Set the default stroke color for any new SVG shape ( .setColor )
- Set the default fill color for any new SVG shape ( .setFill )
- Create a rect object and add it to the svg element ( .rect )
- Create a circle object and add it to the svg element ( .circle )

**First, create some sample markdown:**

(Assumes that all markdown is well-formed and valid)

```
// svg 200, 150 
// set-color black 
// set-fill none 
// rect 0, 0, 200, 150
// set-color #C00 set-fill #F00 
// circle 100, 75, 50

// sample markdown text

var markdown="svg 200, 150\nset-color black\nset-fill none\nrect 0, 0, 200, 150\nset-color #C00\nset-fill #F00\ncircle 100, 75, 50\n"
```

**Then parse that markdown like this:**

```
// create a new Svg object
// this object knows how to create SVG elements

var svg=new Svg();

// strip off trailing return, if present
if(markdown.slice(-1)=="\n"){
    markdown=markdown.slice(0,-1);
}

// split markdown into individual commands
var commands=markdown.split("\n");
```

**Finally, use the Svg class to process each Markup command into the associated SVG**

```
// process each command in commands using the svg object

for(var i=0;i<commands.length;i++){
    processCommand(svg,commands[i]);
    console.log(commands[i]);
}


// this function takes a line of Markup and executes the associated Svg command


function processCommand(svg,commandline){

    // get command and remove command from commandline

    var command=(commandline.split(" ")[0]).toLowerCase();
    commandline=commandline.substr(commandline.indexOf(" ")+1).trim();

    // get args (assuming comma/space delimiters)

    var args=commandline.split(/[ ,]+/);

    // execute the command with svg

    switch(command){
        case "svg":
            svg.setSvgWidthHeight(args[0],args[1])
            break;
        case "set-color":
            svg.setColor(args[0])
            break;
        case "set-fill":
            svg.setFill(args[0])
            break;
        case "rect":
            svg.rect(args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3])
            break;
        case "circle":
            svg.circle(args[0],args[1],args[2])
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

**Here is an Svg “class” object for you to start with:**

```
var Svg = (function () {

    // constructor
    function Svg() {
        this.svgns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        this.xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
        this.nextId=1000;
        this.fill="gray";
        this.stroke="black";
        this.strokeWidth=2;
        this.width =1;
        this.height=1;
        this.svg=document.createElementNS(this.svgns,"svg");
        this.svg.setAttribute('width', this.width);
        this.svg.setAttribute('height', this.height);
        document.body.appendChild(this.svg);
    }
    //
    Svg.prototype.create = function(elementType,fill,stroke,strokeWidth,id){
        var e=document.createElementNS(this.svgns,elementType);
        e.setAttribute("id",id||this.nextId++);
        e.setAttribute("fill",fill||this.fill);
        e.setAttribute("stroke",stroke||this.stroke);
        e.setAttribute("stroke-width",strokeWidth||this.strokeWidth);
        this.svg.appendChild(e);
        return(e);
    }
    //
    Svg.prototype.setSvgWidthHeight = function(width,height){
        this.svg.setAttribute("width",width);
        this.svg.setAttribute("height",height);
        return(this);
    }
    //
    Svg.prototype.rect = function (x,y,width,height) {
        var e=this.create("rect");
        e.setAttribute("x",x);
        e.setAttribute("y",y);
        e.setAttribute("width",width);
        e.setAttribute("height",height);
        e.setAttribute("fill",this.fill);
        e.setAttribute("stroke",this.stroke);
        return(this);
    };
    //
    Svg.prototype.setFill = function(fillcolor){
        this.fill=fillcolor;
        return(this);
    }
    //
    Svg.prototype.setColor = function(strokecolor){
        this.stroke=strokecolor;
        return(this);
    }
    //
    Svg.prototype.circle = function (cx,cy,radius) {
        var e=this.create("circle");
        e.setAttribute("cx",cx);
        e.setAttribute("cy",cy);
        e.setAttribute("r",radius);
        e.setAttribute("fill",this.fill);
        e.setAttribute("stroke",this.stroke);
        return(this);
    };

    return Svg;
})();
```

Comment: Nice. You could use an object instead of your switch : svgCommand = {  svg: Svg.prototype.setSvgWidthHeight , 'set-color' : Svg.prototype.setColor... }; then use something like svgCommand[command].apply(svg, arguments)

Comment: ... And since there's no constraint on the language, we might use the very same keywords on prototype and language to need no translation. ( Svg.prototype[command].apply(svg,arguments); // maybe a check before for proper error message. )

Comment: Agreed...Since the arguments are already in an array, .apply would be a good choice for refactored production code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I was asking for ready parser since I wanted to know if here is some "standartized" syntax. I am really considering writing the thing myself (though in PHP or other server-side language, to have the stuff rendered before output), but you know it is always important to see what is done already before implementing some "innovative idea" :)

Comment: As I mentioned...I haven't seen a published Markdown-to-SVG compiler, although I'm sure it's been done--people like doing cross-compilers for fun!  :)